# Issue with binding Interfaces to implementations

Tags: php, laravel, dependency-injection, laravel-8

In the AppServiceProvider's `boot()` method, I bind an implementation of an interface to it.

```php
// app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php
public function boot()
{
    $this->app->bind(AdjudicatableInterface::class, CliAdjudicator::class);
}
```

In a Job's `__construct()` method, I'd like to have it injected.

```php
// app/Jobs/Play/Adjudicator/ReadVariantProvinces.php
public function __construct(AdjudicatableInterface $adjudicatableInterface, Variant $variant)
{
    $this->variant = $variant;
    $this->adjudicator = $adjudicatableInterface;
}
```

I'm dispatching this job synchronously in a seeder with the following
`ReadVariantProvinces::dispatchSync($variant)`. However I'm getting the following error message:

> TypeError
> App\Jobs\Play\Adjudicator\ReadVariantProvinces::__construct():
> Argument #1 ($adjudicatableInterface) must  be of type
> App\Utility\Adjudicator\AdjudicatableInterface,
> App\Models\Play\Variant given, called in
> /home/pi/www/napoleon/src/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bus/Dispatchable.php
> on line 57

However, according to the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/container#binding-interfaces-to-implementations), I think I am correct. Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: where are you passing a App\Models\Play\Variant?

Comment: In dispatchSync()

Comment: @lagbox the point is that that line does not involve the considered binding at the beginning, so i totally misunderstood the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dispatchSync(...)` is creating a new instance of the Job. There is no dependency injection happening, the container is not involved with resolving the job. What ever parameters you have setup for the constructor you would have to pass yourself.

For dependency injection jobs have a `handle` method that the container calls which allows for method injection. That is where you list your dependencies that you want injected.

[Laravel 8.x Docs - Queues - Jobs - Handle Method Dependency Injection](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queues#handle-method-dependency-injection)

Comment: Thank you. I overread this. Works like a charm.